# android 13 samsung device android.app.RemoteServiceException$CannotPostForegroundServiceNotificationException: Bad notification for startForeground

Tags: android, firebase, samsung-mobile

I tried to test my app but never saw this exception when I tested it. But on The Firebase it shows exceptions very often 99% Samsung devices 99 Android 13 100% in background

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$CannotPostForegroundServiceNotificationException: Bad notification for startForeground
       at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2222)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2508)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```